# How can I make Google Maps speak the street names when the voice is set to a foreign language?

Tags: google, google-maps, languages, google-maps-navigation

I'm running Google Pixel 2 with latest updates. You can change the navigation voice language in Google Maps via:

hamburger icon (3 horizontal bars) --> Settings --> Navigation Settings --> Voice selection --> choose any language

I have my Google maps voice set to French. However, it no longer speaks street names! I am using Google maps to navigate using voice only, with*out* a screen, while riding my electric skateboard. So, I really need it to speak the street names while I'm riding, but I want the voice to be in French. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best answer would be for GOOGLE TO PLEASE FIX IT so we can have an option to turn street name speaking on or off regardless of the chosen system language and the chosen Google Maps spoken language (they should be functionally separate).

However, this is the only current work-around I have been able to discover:

the solution is simply to change your entire phone language to the foreign language you want spoken, as apparently the street names can *only* be spoken in the phone's default language. This is dumb.

**Anyway: main phone settings --> System --> Languages & input --> Languages --> Add a language --> choose the one you want (ex: French) --> tap and hold the hamburger icon (3 horizontal bars) next to this new language and drag it up to re-order this language to be on the very top (it is now your default system language).**

That's it! Now, back in your Google Maps navigation settings you'll see that the default language (French) is now chosen, and under it it says what it used to say for the English default language: "Prononce les noms de rues" (Speak street names). **It now speaks street names in French, just like it used to do for English.** *However, the down-side is that my entire phone is now in French instead of just the audio for my Google Maps, like I wanted. **Google, please fix this!***

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you only need to change the app language, not the phone language.
open Maps, open the profile menu, go to settings and select app language.

Please Google, fix this.

Comment: If this works now to speak the street names in the foreign language, not just the directions in the foreign language, this is new. At the time I wrote [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/211751/121619), it did not.

Answer (score -2):

There's no reason why the above "solution" needs to be so complicated. Open Google maps. Cluck settings. Click navigation. Click language. Click default. 
That's it.

Comment: You should try testing your own answer. This doesn't speak the street names in the foreign language at all. It speaks in a non-foreign language. Then, if you change to a foreign language it only speaks the directions in the foreign language, but won't speak street names anymore. Refer to my question. Read it carefully.